# Not being able to access particular page in ASP .NET application

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6, connection-timeout

I have strange problem and have no idea how to solve it.

I am developing asp. net application using Web forms. Although rest of application works fine, one page is unaccessible. It works fine if I try to display it on machine, that hosts iis and website, however, when I try to reach it from another location, after long period of time server returns error:  Connection timeout.

I narrowed this particular page to simple html with no code-behind to be sure it's not application issue. Nothing changed.

I looked into IIS logs for this event and what I saw was:

2015-02-04 12:52:10 *appname server ip* GET /*page path* - 80 - *browser info* 200 0 121

Which means http response was ok with the sc-win32-status code 121 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.

I've been trying to solve this issue for days now, getting nowhere. I am running out of ideas, any solution or advice how to troubleshoot this one will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Local test working fine usually indicates there is networking issue between the server and problematic client. You can launch tools like webfetch to trace the rawdata of http request/response and determine if the problem is actually on server-side.

HOW TO: Use Wfetch.exe to Troubleshoot HTTP Connections
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;284285

Or you can use Fiddler or Netmon to capture network trace directly which can be more straightforward.

Taken from here: http://forums.iis.net/post/1959520.aspx

Comment: I tried several different clients to reach this page with the same effect. So I think this one is a server issue.